# Kelp+XP farm broken in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

I built a kelp farm (bedrock 1.16.210) like the one described in this video

It was working fine and it suddenly broke. For some reason, when the piston that breaks the kelp retracts, the water does not have time enough to refill the space so the kelp does not grow.

Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Could you add repeaters to slow the pistons down?

Comment: Are you sure the slabs above the pistons are waterlogged?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yes, I tried adding 1 tick to the clock repeater. Adding another repeater to the circuit does not slow down the pistons, just retards them. It didn't work.

Comment: @SF. yes, there was a water source in the slabs.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the farm.

1. I added a flip flop so that the pistons are activated once for each 2 clock cycles. The clock can work either in 1 click or 2 clicks, so the pistons are activated each 2 or 4 clicks.
2. I removed the slabs and placed the water one more block above (that is 2 blocks above the pistons)
   Enjoy your XP!